# Calling unknown method: craft\web\twig\variables\CraftVariable::embeddedAssets()

Tags: templating, plugin-embeddedassets

I get this message while trying to access embedded Asset with the plugin **Embedded Assets 1.0.2**:

**Calling unknown method: craft\web\twig\variables\CraftVariable::embeddedAssets()**

I was fiddling around with the code all evening and aint got no idea,
how to get embedded Assets out of my matrix block.

```
{% case "externeLinks" %}

        {% for asset in block.externalAssets.all() %} 

        {% set embeddedAsset = craft.embeddedAssets.get(asset) %}
            {{ embeddedAsset ? embeddedAsset.html }}
        {% endfor %}

{% endswitch %}
```

If someone could help me, I would really appreciate it. I am new to Craft. If you need any more code, I will provide it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might sound like a silly question, but is the Embedded Assets plugin installed and enabled?